# Ransack multiple words in one search field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

Need some help on this

I have a User model and a Profile model with a has_one relationship (User has one profile, and a profile belongs to only one User, very basic, very simple).

I would like to do something like that :

```
 User.search({:profile_last_name_or_profile_first_name_cont_any=> 'jane doe'.split(' ')}).result
```

the SQL generated is the following

```
"SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ((("profiles"."last_name" ILIKE '%jane%' OR "profiles"."last_name" ILIKE '%doe%') OR ("profiles"."first_name" ILIKE '%jane%' OR "profiles"."first_name" ILIKE '%doe%')))"
```

which returns the expected results... But how to implement this request in my search form (in my view) and/or in my controller ?

My search form is :

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: search_cockpit_users_path, method: 'post', id: 'users-search-form', class: 'span3 pull-right' do |su| %>
      <%= su.text_field :profile_last_name_or_profile_first_name_or_email_cont_any, :placeholder => 'full name or email contains' %>
      <%= su.submit 'Search', :name => nil, :class => 'btn ' %>
  <% end %>
```

As it is the SQL returned is

```
"SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ((("profiles"."last_name" ILIKE '%jane doe%') OR ("profiles"."first_name" ILIKE '%jane doe%')))"
```

but how to implement the split(' ') to have the expected SQL ?

Any help (and a bit of explanation) would be great, documentation is a bit light on the subject...

Cheers

**EDIT following the comment from wintermeyer**

@wintermeyer
Here are the pieces of code you asked for. I don't really see why you need them, the problem is not in the search process which works fine with only one word. My problem is how to split the query string to have the expected generated SQL.

The part of controller involved is

```
class Cockpit::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q = User.joins(:profile).search(params[:q])
    @pp = params[:pp] ? params[:pp].to_i : 10
    @users = @q.result.paginate(:per_page => @pp, :page => params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
      format.js { @users }
    end
  end

  def search
    @q = User.joins(:profile).search(params[:q])

    @pp = params[:pp] ? params[:pp].to_i : 10
    @users = @q.result.paginate(:per_page => @pp, :page => params[:page])
    render "index"
  end
end
```

And the part of routes

```
namespace :cockpit do
    root :to => "dashboard#index"

    resources :users do
      member do
        get 'toggle_remove'
      end

      collection do
        get 'bulk'
        match 'search', to: "users#search", via: [:get, :post], as: 'search'
      end

      resources :profiles
    end
  end
```

Comment: You need to add the controller and the essential part of the routes.rb  to this question.